# CM 12.1 Nexus 5 stuck on bootloop and recovery load-up

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-5, boot-loop, unbricking, twrp

I've got quite a peculiar problem with my Nexus 5.

Last night, I left my phone on charge. It was working normally and the software was functional etc. However, once I woke up, the phone was constantly restarting itself, and wouldn't load past the boot animation. I tried to load up fastboot to enter the TWRP recovery, however, the phone froze on the load screen. I should also add that my custom boot animation was replaced by the CyanogenMod mascot.

This problem has never occurred before, and I really haven't got a clue how to fix it. I tried to use WugFresh's NRT to flash a factory image of Android 6, however, the command terminal indicated that each process had failed. This did not restore the phone to its original condition.

I should also point out that I have been running a CM 12.1 nightly, which has been very stable and I have been using this nightly, without major problems (bar the infrequent system UI crashes) for a couple of months. It is obviously rooted and I have a Nandroid backup, which I can't access for aforementioned reasons.

Please could you help me with resurrecting my phone? I would be happy to clarify and elaborate upon any point of information.

Kind regards,

Sami

Comment: When the device is starting (even stuck and repeat reboot ) if you plug it to PC is it detected by adb ? If so can you post a logcat of the boot process

Comment: It just displays 'list of devices attached' and that's it- no serial numbers of anything, even in fastboot. When in fastboot, I typed 'adb reboot-bootloader' it just said 'error:device not found'

Comment: If in fastboot, you'll have to use the fastboot command to reboot the phone as **fastboot reboot**. You can also check for **fastboot devices** using the same as a command. You can also try flashing the factory image manually from [Android Developers](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en) by following the numerous guides posted on the net.